# getJSON API URL Parameters

Tags: javascript, api, getjson

I am nearing completion of my project and am attempted to build the URL to make a getJSON call but am getting a 404 error where my API URL is not formatting properly.  I've watched some youtube videos and searched this site and thought I had it written properly but I cannot locate what I did incorrectly.

Here is my script

```js
$(() => {
  var api = 'https://api.worldweatheronline.com/premium/v1/marine.ashx?&q=';
  var wwolat = 'document.querySelector("#lat"),';
  var wwolng = 'document.querySelector("#lng")';
  var apikey = '&key=MY_KEY';
  var format = '&format';
  var url = api + wwolat + wwolng + apikey + format;

  $.getJSON('url', function(data) {
    console.log(data);

    var date24 = data.data.weather[1].date;
    var air24 = data.data.weather[1].hourly[4].tempF;
    var wnsd24 = data.data.weather[1].hourly[4].windspeedMiles;
    var wndr24 = data.data.weather[1].hourly[4].winddir16Point;
    var height1 = data.data.weather[1].hourly[4].swellHeight_ft;
    var wvht24 = Math.floor(height1);
    var wvdr24 = data.data.weather[1].hourly[4].swellDir16Point;
    var per1 = data.data.weather[1].hourly[4].swellPeriod_secs;
    var wvpd24 = Math.floor(per1);
    var cloud24 = data.data.weather[1].hourly[4].cloudcover;

    $(".date24").append(date24);
    $(".air24").append(air24);
    $(".wnsd24").append(wnsd24);
    $(".wndr24").append(wndr24);
    $(".wvht24").append(wvht24);
    $(".wvdr24").append(wvdr24);
    $(".wvpd24").append(wvpd24);
    $(".cloud24").append(cloud24);

    var date48 = data.data.weather[2].date;
    var air48 = data.data.weather[2].hourly[4].tempF;
    var wnsd48 = data.data.weather[2].hourly[4].windspeedMiles;
    var wndr48 = data.data.weather[2].hourly[4].winddir16Point;
    var height2 = data.data.weather[2].hourly[4].swellHeight_ft
    var wvht48 = Math.floor(height2);
    var wvdr48 = data.data.weather[2].hourly[4].swellDir16Point;
    var per2 = data.data.weather[2].hourly[4].swellPeriod_secs
    var wvpd48 = Math.floor(per2);
    var cloud48 = data.data.weather[2].hourly[4].cloudcover;

    $(".date48").append(date48);
    $(".air48").append(air48);
    $(".wnsd48").append(wnsd48);
    $(".wndr48").append(wndr48);
    $(".wvht48").append(wvht48);
    $(".wvdr48").append(wvdr48);
    $(".wvpd48").append(wvpd48);
    $(".cloud48").append(cloud48);

  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: One thing I noticed: ```var apikey = '&key=MY_KEY';``` You should put your actual API key in.

Comment: Thanks @RichardLovell I removed my key as to not make it public.  The proper key is in the actual script.

Answer (score 0):

You have `url` enclosed in quotes in your `$.getJSON` call. You need to remove the quotes so it can be interpreted as a variable otherwise it is interpreted as a string.

```
$.getJSON(url, ... )
```

Comment: Thanks @Pablo  I tried it without and am still getting the                                         
       Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () 
      apiwwolatwwolngapikeyformat:1